# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # # SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff81779403f, pid=94133, tid=259

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crash-reports, java-runtime-compiler

I'm getting this error and my editor is getting closed automatically.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff81779403f, pid=94133, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-11.0.14.1.1-2043.25-jcef (11.0.14.1+1) (build 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-11.0.14.1.1-2043.25-jcef (11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0xd03f]  objc_release+0x1f
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

I'm running this command `ulimit -c unlimited`, but every time I open the editor, I need to run this command which sucks. Is there any permanent solution for this?

*Here is the complete error - [gist](https://gist.github.com/ravireddy07/ad81c4da4c586e03370e422d80642dd5)*

Comment: The problem could be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4351 . Please update the IDE to the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download .